# Changing the layout of an array in output

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, grid-layouts

I'm curious about the following: if I want to make a table described by the following code,

```
TableForm[
    Table[Plot[Sin[ n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> {150, 150}], {n, 1, 
15}]
]
```

How will I be able to arrange it into a 3 by 5 table instead of a 1 by 15?

Comment: `Multicolumn[
 Table[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> {150, 150}], {n, 1, 
   15}], 5]`  Or `Multicolumn[
 Table[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> {150, 150}], {n, 1, 
   15}], 5, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]`

Comment: Thank you this is good! Also the previous answer using Partition[table,3] works great as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your table

```
table = Table[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> {150, 150}], {n, 1, 15}];
```

Here are three different ways to do it,

```
TableForm[ArrayReshape[table, {3, 5}]]

Multicolumn[table, {3, 5}]

Grid[Partition[table, 5]]
```